# How to get simple paint application using Tkinter library in python to show results on screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, pixel

```
 from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Paint():
    def __init__(self):

        self.window=Tk()
        self.sizex=500
        self.sizey=500


        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=self.sizex, height=self.sizey, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.img = PhotoImage(width=self.sizex, height=self.sizey)
        self.canvas.create_image((self.sizex, self.sizey), image=self.img, state="normal")
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>",self.color_in)

    def color_in(self, event):
        self.img.put("black", (event.x, event.y))
paint=Paint()
mainloop()
```

In the code above, I can get a blank white window to open, but when I click anywhere on the screen there is no change. How do I get the window to update?

Comment: For one, 3/4 of the image is off screen, so you're probably writing to a pixel that  you can't see. You're putting the center of the image in the bottom-right corner of the window.

Comment: Good effort. You can take a look at this repository, if you want to add additional features. It is still under development though: https://github.com/EshitaShukla/Paint_Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

You should only import Tkinter once. If you import it as "tk" your code will be easier to understand.

If you set different colors to the different widgets it will be easy to see if they are where you want them to be.

When you place the image on the canvas you put it at position 500, 500 which is in the lower right corner. The default anchor is at the center of the image. This results in you only seeing the upper left 1/4 of the image, as Bryan points out.

I have repositioned the image to (0,0) and assigned the upper left corner ('nw') as anchor. Also canvas `highlightthickness=0` removes a 2 pixel highlight border from the canvas. Image `state='normal'` is the default.

Lastly I made the mark placed on the image a bit larger to make it easier to see. And I adjusted the call to `mainloop()`

The image updates automatically, now that it's in the right position.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Paint():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.sizex = 500
        self.sizey = 500
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width=self.sizex,
                             height=self.sizey, highlightthickness=0)
        # Set canvas background color so you can see it
        self.canvas.config(bg="thistle")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(width=self.sizex, height=self.sizey)
        self.canvas.create_image((0,0), image=self.img, state="normal",
                                 anchor='nw')
        # Set image color so you can see it
        self.img.put('khaki',to=(0, 0, self.sizex, self.sizey))
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>",self.color_in)

    def color_in(self, event):
        # Paint a 2x2 square at the mouse position on image
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        self.img.put("black", to=(x-2, y-2, x+2, y+2))

paint = Paint()
paint.window.mainloop()
```